# How can I speed up my MySQL query (JOINs + GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query in mysql and since it take almost 20 sec to execute, I want to do selects insted of innerjoins with limits in order to make the execution faster.

```
SELECT t1.order_id, CONCAT(t3.first_name,' ',t3.last_name),
    buyer_first_name, buyer_last_name, 
    max(product_quantity) as product_quantity, order_status, 
    order_value, t5.first_name staff_firstnamelogin, 
    t5.last_name staff_lastnamelogin, t6.day_name

FROM t_seller_order t0

INNER JOIN t_orders t1
                ON t0.event_id = t1.event_id 
               AND t1.seller_order_token = t0.seller_order_token

INNER JOIN t_tickets t2
                ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id

INNER JOIN t_login t3
                ON t3.login_id = t1.login_id

INNER JOIN t_login t5
                ON t0.login_id = t5.login_id

INNER JOIN t_event_days t6
                ON t2.product_id = t6.event_day_id

WHERE t0.event_id = 35

group by t1.order_id

order by order_id desc;
```

Comment: Well, do you have the proper indexes created, and are they being utilized?

Comment: #1 reason for slow performance is inadequate index coverage. Check that all these columns involved in the joins, and there are a lot of them, have an associated `INDEX`. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command can show you what indexes are defined. `EXPLAIN` can help identify missing indexes.

Comment: Give Explain statement result for this query and table structures as well with index details (if any)

Comment: Not yet. how can i do it in this exemple?

Comment: There could be a number of ways to improve your query.  We do need some more information about what you're doing.  What are your table structures, are they indexed, have they been optimized, what server/computer stats are you using, how much memory do you have utilized to mysql, how much memory do you have utilized to indexing?

Comment: I don't think multiple queries (even with limits) will be faster than a single one. Please add the execution plan. You can get it by running: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Hard to help you without knowing which columns are in which tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things about the schema that prevent speeding up the query.  Let's see what can or cannot be done...

Since the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` hit different tables, no index is useful for both.  The best is to have `t0`: **`INDEX(event_id)`**.

**Indexes for JOINs**:  t2..t6 need indexes (or PKs) on `order_id`, `login_id`, `event_day_id`.  `t1` needs `INDEX(event_id, seller_order_token)` in either order.

The `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the 'same', so that will take only one sort, not two.

A potential speedup is to finish the `GROUP BY` *before* doing some of the `JOINs`.  The current structure is "inflate-deflate", wherein the `JOINs` conspire to create a huge temp table, then the `GROUP BY` deflates the results.  So...

If see if you can write a `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT t0.id, t1.id  -- I need the PRIMARY KEYs for these two tables
    FROM t_seller_order AS t0
    JOIN t_orders       AS t1
    WHERE t0.event_id = 35
    GROUP BY t1.order_id
```

How fast is that?  Hopefully we can build the rest of the query around this, but without taking too much more time.  There are two approaches; I don't know which will be better.

**Plan A:**  Use subqueries (when possible) instead of `JOINs`.  For example, instead of `JOINing to t3, plan on this being one item in the`SELECT`:

```
    ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)
          FROM t_login WHERE login_id = t1.login_id
    ) AS login_name
```

(Ditto for any other columns in the `SELECT` that touch a table only once.  As it stands, t5 is touched twice, so this approach may be impractical.)

**Plan B:**  `JOIN` *after* the `GROUP BY`.  That is, after then "deflate".

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT t0.id, t1.id ... GROUP BY... ) AS x -- as discussed above
    JOIN y  ON y.foo = x.foo
    JOIN z  ON z.bar = x.bar
    -- the GROUP BY is avoided
    ORDER BY x.order_id desc;   -- The ORDER BY is still necessary
```

Is your example, I lean toward Plan B, but a mixture of both 'Plans' may be desirable.

Further notes:  `LEFT JOIN` and `LIMIT` add wrinkles to the above discussion.  Since you did not have either, I will not clutter this discussion with them.